# returning a string per element using substring-after

Tags: python, xpath, substring, lxml

I can return a list of strings if I map to the element attribute:

```
In [15]: root
Out[15]: <Element ADI at 0x7f4b5e6ad188>

In [16]: root = et.fromstring('<a><c><b value="the.never.ending.tale.99999.gz"/><b value="the.never.ending.tale.999745745799.gz"/><b value="the.never.ending.tale.99951351399.gz"/></c></a>')

In [23]: root.xpath('./c/b/@value')
Out[23]:
['the.never.ending.tale.99999.gz',
 'the.never.ending.tale.999745745799.gz',
 'the.never.ending.tale.99951351399.gz']
```

However I can't return a list of substrings using:

```
In [24]: root.xpath('./c/b/substring-after(@value,"never")')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
XPathEvalError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-16664f97a745> in <module>()
----> 1 root.xpath('./c/b/substring-after(@value,"never")')

src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx in lxml.etree._Element.xpath (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:57924)()

src/lxml/xpath.pxi in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:167085)()

src/lxml/xpath.pxi in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:166044)()

XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
```

What mistake have I made here?

Comment: What you want can't be done in XPath 1.0; I'd just get the substrings you want with a list comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment, you can't write a single expression in XPath 1.0 returning a sequence or list of strings, however, if you use list comprehensions, you can use the following approach:

```
el = ET.fromstring('<a><c><b value="the.never.ending.tale.99999.gz"/><b value="the.never.ending.tale.999745745799.gz"/><b value="the.never.ending.tale.99951351399.gz"/></c></a>')
values = [b.xpath('substring-after(@value, "never")') for b in el.xpath('c/b')]
```

which then gives

```
>>> values
['.ending.tale.99999.gz', '.ending.tale.999745745799.gz', '.ending.tale.99951351399.gz']
```